# Binary tree - Reverse traversal with forward iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, binary-tree, traversal

I have implemented a `struct Node<class  A, class B>` with key `A` and data `B`, holding `left`, `right` and `parent` nodes.

For the tree that can be built with nodes, I want to implement an iterator class `BTIT`, also as a template with `A` and `B`.  I have implemented `begin` and `rbegin` returning the left-most and right-most nodes in the tree respectively. `end` and `rend` returning a `BTIT(nullptr)` so to know when at the end.

The `operator++` for the iterator class is implemented as

```
BTIT<A, B>& operator++() {
  curr = curr->nodeN();
  return *this;
}
```

together with an algorithm for finding the next node in the tree as follows

```
Node<A, B>* nextN() {
  Node<A, B> *curr = this;
  if (curr == nullptr) {
    return curr;
  };
  if (curr->right != nullptr) {
    curr = curr->right;
    while(curr->left != nullptr) {
      curr = curr->left;
    };
  }
  else {
    Node<A, B> *par = curr->parent;
    while (par != nullptr && curr == par->right) {
      curr = par;
      par = par->parent;
    };
    curr = par;
  };
  return curr;
};
```

This works fine for iterating in a for-loop using `begin` and `end` to print the tree's data values `B` in order. However, the `operator++` is also supposed to work for reversed order, i.e. for `rbegin` and `rend`, but then it only prints the right-most node and stops. I can see how the algorithm above won't work for reversed order. My question is, how can it be augmented so to work for both `begin`/`end` and `rbegin`/`rend`? What's the idea? I have a hard time figuring this out, and where to start.

**EDIT:** I've implemented an algorithm for reversed traversal as follows

```
Node<A, B>* prevN() {
  Node<A, B> *curr = this;
  if (curr == nullptr) {
    return curr;
  };
  if (curr->left != nullptr) {
    curr = curr->left;
    while(curr->right != nullptr) {
      curr = curr->right;
    };
  }
  else {
    Node<A, B> *par = curr->parent;
    while (par != nullptr && curr == par->left) {
      curr = par;
      par = par->parent;
    };
    curr = par;
  };
  return curr;
};
```

which works for iterating in a for-loop with `rbegin` and `rend` with decrementing (--it) the iterator object. Now, I want to work by printing in reversed order using

```
for (auto it = root->rbegin(); it != root->rend(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << endl;
```

as well. Is it possible?

Comment: You don't augment the same function, you create a new `reverse_iterator` class.

Comment: The shown code iterates over the tree in the forward direction. How exactly did you expect it to iterate in the other direction, without having written a single line of code that actual does that? Things ... just don't happen like that, in C++.

Comment: @sweenish Yes, thank you. That's one good idea of course. However, is it possible to implement within the same class?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't expect it. The problem I'm having is getting started and understanding the idea of how to do it and have one class that can handle both forward and reversed. The shown code is what I have for the forward direction.

Comment: Ok, well, before you can actually figure out how to make something that's compatible with the C++ library, you have to actually implement the basic algorithm. This has to be done in every case. So, start by writing some function that iterates over the tree in the other direction. Call it `operator--`, for example. Now, once you actually have the functionality implemented, then you can begin to think about how to make `rbegin` and `rend` work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, you are right. I have now updated my question with the algorithm for reversed order using a prevN() function. It works with a decrementing iterator --it in a for-loop, but I want it to work with ++it as well. Do you any more tips? Thank you!

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you're asking. You have implemented forward and reverse iteration. I see nothing that needs to be done here. Just declare an `operator--` overload, thta uses that, and that's it.

Comment: @Defindun No. You want a single function to do two opposite actions, based on what? If you want an `operator++` to go backwards, you create a new class for a reverse iterator, just like the Standard Library does. Or, you just change the name to `operator--` for your current iterator. And this is before we get into the idea that you're essentially declaring only one method of traversal as canonical for your class. Anyone who wants preorder or postorder is likely out of luck, then?